# Conditional filtering of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, filter, slice

I have a pandas data frame about football results. Each row of the dataframe represents a football match. The information of each match are:

```
Day | WinningTeamID | LosingTeamID | WinningPoints | LosingPoints | WinningFouls | ... | 
1          13             1              45                5               3  
1          12             4              21                12              4
```

That is, the information are divided based on the game result: winning or losing. 
I would like to retrieve the data of each game for a specific team (e.g. 12).

```
Day | Points | Fouls | ... | 
1       21       4     ...
2       32       6     ...
```

The simplest way is to scan the whole dataframe, check if a specific teamID is on **WinningID** or **LosingID** and then, based on that, retrieve the "*Losing-columns*" or the "*Winning-columns*".
Is there a more "elegant" way of slicing the pandas dataframe?
This will simply give me the subset of matches where the team 12 is involved.

```
df[df[WinningTeamID == 12] | [LosingTeamID == 12]]
```

How can I filter those data and create the desired dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we could choose the format of the data. What would be ideal?  Since we
want to collect stats per `TeamID`, ideally we would have a column of `TeamID`s
and separate columns for each stat including the outcome.

So the data would look like this:

```
| Day | Outcome | TeamID | Points | Fouls |
|   1 | Winning |     13 |     45 |     3 |
|   1 | Losing  |      1 |      5 |   NaN |
|   1 | Winning |     12 |     21 |     4 |
|   1 | Losing  |      4 |     12 |   NaN |
```

Here is how we can manipulate the given data into the desired form:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': [1, 1], 'LosingPoints': [5, 12], 'LosingTeamID': [1, 4], 'WinningFouls': [3, 4], 'WinningPoints': [45, 21], 'WinningTeamID': [13, 12]})
df = df.set_index(['Day'])
columns = df.columns.to_series().str.extract(r'^(Losing|Winning)?(.*)', expand=True)
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([columns[col] for col in columns], 
                                    names=['Outcome', None])
df.columns = columns
df = df.stack(level='Outcome').reset_index()
print(df)
```

yields

```
   Day  Outcome  Fouls  Points  TeamID
0    1   Losing    NaN       5       1
1    1  Winning    3.0      45      13
2    1   Losing    NaN      12       4
3    1  Winning    4.0      21      12
```

Now we can obtain all the stats about `TeamID` 12 using

```
print(df.loc[df['TeamID']==12])
#    Day  Outcome  Fouls  Points  TeamID
# 3    1  Winning    4.0      21      12
```

---

[`df = df.set_index(['Day'])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) moves the `Day` column into the index.

The purpose of placing `Day` in the index is to "protect" it from manipulations
(primarily the `stack` call) that are intended only for columns labeled `Losing` or `Winning`. If you had other columns, such as `Location` or
`Officials` which, like `Day`, do not pertain to `Losing` or `Winning`, then
you'd want to include them in the `set_index` call too: e.g.  `df =
df.set_index(['Day', 'Location', 'Officials'])`.

Try commenting out `df = df.set_index(['Day'])` from the code above. Then step through the code line-by-line.
In particular, compare what [`df.stack(level='Outcome')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) looks like with and without the `set_index` call:

With `df = df.set_index(['Day'])`:

```
In [26]: df.stack(level='Outcome')
Out[26]: 
             Fouls  Points  TeamID
Day Outcome                       
1   Losing     NaN       5       1
    Winning    3.0      45      13
    Losing     NaN      12       4
    Winning    4.0      21      12
```

Without `df = df.set_index(['Day'])`:

```
In [29]: df.stack(level='Outcome')
Out[29]: 
           Day  Fouls  Points  TeamID
  Outcome                            
0 NaN      1.0    3.0      45      13
  Losing   NaN    NaN       5       1
  Winning  1.0    3.0      45      13
1 NaN      1.0    4.0      21      12
  Losing   NaN    NaN      12       4
  Winning  1.0    4.0      21      12
```

Without the `set_index` call you end up with rows that you do not want -- the rows where `Outcome` equals `NaN`.

---

The purpose of

```
columns = df.columns.to_series().str.extract(r'^(Losing|Winning)?(.*)', expand=True)
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([columns[col] for col in columns], 
                                    names=['Outcome', None])
```

is to create a multi-level column index (called a
[MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)) which
labels columns `Losing` or `Winning` as appropriate. 
Notice that by separating out the `Losing` or `Winning` parts of the labels, 
the remaining parts of the labels become duplicated.

We end up with a DataFrame, `df`, with two columns labeled "Points" for example.
This allows Pandas to identify these columns as somehow similar.

The big gain -- the reason why we went through the trouble of setting up the MultiIndex is so that these "similar" columns can be "unified" by calling [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]: 
Outcome Losing        Winning              
        Points TeamID   Fouls Points TeamID
Day                                        
1            5      1       3     45     13
1           12      4       4     21     12

In [48]: df.stack(level="Outcome")
Out[48]: 
             Fouls  Points  TeamID
Day Outcome                       
1   Losing     NaN       5       1
    Winning    3.0      45      13
    Losing     NaN      12       4
    Winning    4.0      21      12
```

---

`stack`, `unstack`, `set_index` and `reset_index` are the 4 fundamental DataFrame reshaping operations.

- [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) moves a level (or levels) of the column index into the row index.
- [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) moves a level (or levels) of the row index into the column index.
- [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) moves column values into the row index
- [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) moves a level (or levels) of the row index into a column of values

Together, these 4 methods allow you to move data in your DataFrame anywhere you
want -- in the columns, the row index or the column index.

The above code is an example of how to use these tools (well, three of the four)
to [reshape data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking) into a desired form.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely does the job! I am fairly new to pandas, could you please explain to me why you use set_index on 'Day'? And what is the aim of the following line?The only part that I understand is that you extract the columns that contain Losing or Winning.

Answer (score 6):

You can filter your dataframe essentially using a where clause. The `.query` option allows you to pass a condition to your Pandas dataframe. Here is how you can do it for your specific question.

```
df.query['WinningTeamID == 12 | LosingTeamID == 12']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The .query option in pandas dataframe makes it easier to pass SQL query like to select data

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be more like:

```
df.query('columnX == 15 | columnY == 25')
```