# any efficient way to cycle through columns with its value list for conditional filtering in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am trying to filter the dataframe conditionally where I intend to cycle through the columns and its values list for conditional filtering but the resulted dataframe was not filtered correctly. I used a known filtering approach for pandas dataframe on `SO` such as [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441783/pandas-conditional-filter), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608005/conditional-filtering-of-pandas-data-frame) and I want to parameterize these data selection processes in the function but cycle through the columns with value list is not working correctly. Any possible idea to overcome this issue? any thought?

**minimal reproducible example**:

here is the [minimal reproducible example on gist](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/851b7f1814e7f3f5a658bce8441e0b8d) that I used in my attempt.

**my attempt**:

I tried this approach and it worked pretty good but I want to parameterize in the function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('minimal_df.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df= df[(df['meat_type']=='Beef') & (df['trade_type']=='E') & (df['origin']=='US') & (df['date'] >'2014-01-01') & (df['date'] <'2019-01-01')]
```

as I said, I want to wrap up a data filtering function so I may do something like this:

```
def data_filter(df, colList, vaList, startDate, endDate):
    for col in colList:
        for val in vaList:
            masker = df[df[col]==val]
            masker.reset_index(drop=True)
            masker = masker.loc[(masker['date']> startDate) & (masker['date'] < endDate)]
    return masker

columns = ['meat_type', 'temperature','origin']
values = ['Beef', 'Frozen','US']
dat_filter(df=df, colList=columns, vaList=values, startDate='2013-12-31', endDate='2019-01-01')
```

but such an attempt doesn't work for me because resulted filtered dataframe wasn't filtered actually. Any idea to make this work correctly?

How can I make my function even more efficient such as instead of using array as parameter is there any better way to pass parameter to the function so we can select multiple columns with value list? any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **pd.query** to achieve this.

First create a query string and pass it to the function.

A sample query string looks like this:

```
'meat_type=="Beef"&temperature=="Frozen"&origin=="US"&startDate>"2013-12-31"&endDate<"2019-01-01"'
```

For parameterization, you can use it in two ways:

- pass columns and values as list
- make columns as parameters using kwargs

The two functions are as below:

```
def filter_1(df, startDate, endDate, date_colname="date", cols=None, vals=None, inplace=False):
  s = ''
  for i,j in zip(cols,vals):
      s += '{}=="{}"&'.format(i,j)

  s += '{}>"{}"&'.format(date_colname, startDate)
  s += '{}<"{}"'.format(date_colname, endDate)
  return df.query(s, inplace=inplace)

def filter_2(df, startDate, endDate, date_colname="date", inplace=False, **kwargs):
  s = ''
  for i,j in kwargs.items():
      s += '{}=="{}"&'.format(i,j)

  s += '{}>"{}"&'.format(date_colname, startDate)
  s += '{}<"{}"'.format(date_colname, endDate)
  return df.query(s, inplace=inplace)

print(filter_1(df, startDate, endDate, cols=columns, vals=values))

print(filter_2(df, startDate, endDate, meat_type='Beef', temperature='Frozen', origin='US'))
```

Comment: @ Asetti sri harsha hmm, this may not be feasible, I mean can't we do this programmatically instead of making query first. what if I intend to filter more columns and bunch of values, how to handle that?

Comment: @Jerry, As you can see in the code, if you create the columnlist and valuelist properly, the query is being created through a loop. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ Asetti sri harsha instead of creating such query, can't be done with parameterizing? that's what I am trying actually. there much be a way to make this as elegant as efficient like nice function.

Comment: Just keep this code inside a function with df,colList,vaList,startDate,endDate as parameters and return data_filtered. This serves the purpose.

Comment: @ Asetti sri harsha the point is this attempt is not quite flexible to use

Comment: @Jerry how do you define flexible? The interface to pandas is explained already in this answer. I was actually testing something rather similar to answer to your question. I just didn't publish it because Asetti answered first.

Comment: @ MkWTF yes, flexible like pass columns and values that you want to filter in the dataframe to the function, instead of making query string first then do `pd.query()`. I think using cycle through columns and values for conditional filtering might be way to do this. in my attempt, that didn't work though.

Comment: @Jerry I made an example of what Asetti is talking about: https://repl.it/repls/SorrowfulLovableBot
I created 2 examples of functions that encapsulate the answer in different manners. Is it missing any use case to be flexible? If so, which one?

Comment: @  MkWTF publish it as an answer so I am gonna accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Asettisriharsha you can add my code snippet to your answer if you want, I was just translating your comment from english to python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207848/discussion-between-jerry-and-mkwtf).