# Any way to get correct output after passing positional named argument (*args, **kwargs) to function?

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

I was trying to filter dataframe based on the list of named arguments, thanks to @MkWTF on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210583/any-efficient-way-to-cycle-through-columns-with-its-value-list-for-conditional-f/60211155?noredirect=1#comment106501854_60211155). However, I want to use `*args` as an argument to loop through then use the filtering function, which means I am going to have a list of filtered dataframe based on named argument as an output.

in my case, I need to use `cty_rpt` column as named argument (`*args`) to loop through the country code then use filtering function to get filtered dataframe:

**minimal data**

here is the minimal data that posted on [gist minimal data](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/b778f087745f73e46dcb9e1ace7b47b0)

**attempt**:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('mydf.csv', encoding='utf-8')
def data_filter(df, startDate, endDate, date_colname="date", inplace=False, **kwargs):
  s = ''
  for i,j in kwargs.items():
      s += '{}=="{}"&'.format(i,j)
  s += '{}>"{}"&'.format(date_colname, startDate)
  s += '{}<"{}"'.format(date_colname, endDate)
  return df.query(s, inplace=inplace)
```

the idea is first subset `df` by looping through its `df.cty_rpt` then each subsetted dataframe further filtered by list of `**kwargs`, which would make list of filtered dataframe.

I feel like above attempt might be realized as follow:

**new attempt to change the definition of my function**

```
def func1(df, *args, startDate, endDate, date_col='date', inplace=False, **kwargs):
    output = []
    for arg in pd.unique(args):
        s = ''
        for i, j in kwargs.items():
            s += '{}=="{}"&'.format(i,j)
        s += '{}>"{}"&'.format(date_colname, startDate)
        s += '{}<"{}"'.format(date_colname, endDate)
        res = df.query(s, inplace=inplace)
        res = df.query(arg, inplace=False)
        output.append(res)
    return output

func1(df, df.cty_rpt,startDate='2013-12-31', endDate='2019-01-01', meat_type='Beef', temperature='Chilled',flow='E')
```

but I got empty list, I don't understand what's going on here. Any idea? where is the bug of my attempt? any quick solution on that?

**goal**:

I want to get a list of dataframe where each dataframe can be filtered by country code wise. I was explicitly looping through `df.cty_rpt` then use `dataa_filter` function, but I feel like using `*args` would simplify that but I couldn't get what I actually need. Any idea to get this done? thanks

Comment: can you try putting *args at the end , instead of second position

Comment: I don't understand how `pd.unique(args)` works when you are feeding it a `df.ctr_rpt` series.

Comment: @MohitSharma - All of the arguments after `*args` are keyword arguments. `startDate` doesn't have a default so it must be present in the call. Its okay to have `*args` early as long as you don't mind filling in the later non-defaulted kw args.

Comment: @tdelaney because `df.cty_rpt`is duplicated, so I need the only loop through distinctive values such as using `set(df.cty_rpt)` or `pd.unique(df.cty_rpt)`. I am trying to figure out how to make this happen by using named argument in python function. Can you guide me some point to make this work? How can I make attempted python function works for the data that I posted on gist? Thank you

Comment: can you show us sample input df (with reproducible code) and desired outputs

Comment: But args is a tuple of input params. In your case `df.cty_rpt` is args[0]. You are doing `pd.unique((dt.cty_rpt,))`.

Comment: Would `for arg in args` make more sense?

Comment: @tdelaney yes, I was trying to loop through the distinctive values of `df.cty_rpt` and tried to adopt this to named arguments in the function, but didn't work to me. Since I posted my workable solution and minimal data here, any possible trick from you? Thanks

Comment: @tdelaney the answer you posted is really awesome, learned another trick, thanks +1

Comment: @tdelaney I am just wondering why we need to explicitly saying `startDate`, `endDate`, `date_col` as default named argument? since we used `**kwargs` for that,  do we need to call it, why?

Comment: @tdelaney I find out one more problem, `startDate`, `endDate` is not actually working when we do filtering, why? I think in your code, `startDate`, `endDate` never used, is that why?

Comment: @Jerry - they aren't working but I considered that to be secondary to your primary question. There is something in setting up the date column on import or how dates are handled in the query engine. I'm not sure, so I just marked as needing debug. If you can't fix it, then its a great new question here on SO. If it were me, I'd cook up a smaller bit of test code focusing just on importing and querying dates to work it out. Good luck!

Comment: @tdelaney I tried like this [my follow up attempt](https://repl.it/repls/ThunderousJovialMicrostation) and it worked but I have to do query twice. any better idea to make the code efficient? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this gets you part way there. With your `*args` strategy, it appears that you want to query on unique values in (potentially) several columns. You can use `pd.unique` to get unique values from any one column and an outer for to extend that to multiple columns. I don't know how you want to handle multiple columns exactly, so I just guessed on one way.

You can build most of the query before starting the loop for unique cty_rpt values. Do it an a list and build the string per query.

I couldn't get this to work when adding in the start/end dates, so I left it commented out.

```
import pandas as pd

def func1(df, *args, startDate, endDate, date_col='date', inplace=False, **kwargs):
    output = []
    query_terms = ['{}=="{}"'.format(*item) for item in kwargs.items()]

    # Todo: This didn't work for me, date query needs to be debugged
    # query_terms += [
    #    '{}>"{}"'.format(date_col, startDate),
    #    '{}<"{}"'.format(date_col, endDate)]

    for series in args:
        for name in pd.unique(series):
            print('querying', series.name, name)
            s = "&".join(query_terms + ['{}=="{}"'.format(series.name, name)])
            res = df.query(s, inplace=inplace) # todo: i think inplace should always be false
            output.append(res)
    return output

df = pd.read_csv("mydf.csv", encoding="utf-8")
print(df)
result = func1(df, df.cty_rpt,startDate='2013-12-31', endDate='2019-01-01', meat_type='Beef', temperature='Chilled',flow='E')

for res in result:
    print('------------------------------')
    print(res)
```

Output

```
    Unnamed: 0 flow cty_rpt     origin           destination      value      qty1       date animal_type meat_type temperature
0            0    E      AR  Argentina               Albania  115691.00  18.26200   1/1/2017      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
1            1    I      AR  Argentina               Albania   72425.20  19.17100   1/1/2016      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
2            2    I      US  Argentina                Angola  109523.15  50.94100   5/1/2014      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
3            3    E      US  Argentina  United Arab Emirates    1078.00   0.15300  10/1/2014      Bovine      Beef     Chilled
4            4    E      US  Argentina               Albania    3373.00   0.26200  12/1/2014      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
5            5    E      US  Argentina                Angola   36308.77   9.55494   4/1/2015      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
6            6    E      AR  Argentina                Angola   10654.65   0.87569   6/1/2017      Bovine      Pork     Chilled
7            7    E      AR  Argentina  United Arab Emirates      86.50   0.02000   7/1/2016      Bovine      Pork     Chilled
8            8    I      AR  Argentina                Angola   68797.00  12.12000   1/1/2014      Bovine      Beef     Chilled
9            9    I     AUC  Argentina                Angola   42000.00  21.00000   2/1/2017      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
10          10    I     AUC  Argentina               Albania  180078.00  26.79100  12/1/2017      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
11          11    I     AUC  Argentina                Angola  194402.47  45.29000   1/1/2015      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
12          12    I     AUC  Argentina  United Arab Emirates   97928.05   6.47850   1/1/2014      Bovine      Pork     Chilled
13          13    E      US  Argentina                Angola   61430.00  10.85000   4/1/2014      Bovine      Beef     Chilled
14          14    E      US  Argentina                Angola    4153.80   1.97800  12/1/2014      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
15          15    E      US  Argentina               Albania   55599.30  10.29300   6/1/2014      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
16          16    I      US  Argentina                Angola   11531.00   0.20100  10/1/2014      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
17          17    I      AR  Argentina  United Arab Emirates    1908.50   0.17800   4/1/2017      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
18          18    I      AR  Argentina                Angola   59476.10  10.85600   1/1/2018      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
19          19    E      CN  Argentina                Angola  452174.70  74.82600  12/1/2014      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
20          20    E      CN  Argentina               Albania  101596.00  13.57200  11/1/2014      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
21          21    E      KR  Argentina                Angola  135035.00  27.00700   5/1/2014      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
22          22    E      KR  Argentina                Angola   86506.00  46.76000  10/1/2015      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
23          23    I      KR  Argentina             Argentina  300876.85  24.53188   3/1/2014      Bovine      Beef     Chilled
24          24    E      KR  Argentina               Albania  475380.06  72.74437   9/1/2015      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
25          25    E      AR  Argentina               Albania   80396.00   8.77800   1/1/2018      Bovine      Pork      Frozen
26          26    I      AR  Argentina  United Arab Emirates     160.00   0.02000  11/1/2014      Bovine      Pork     Chilled
27          27    I      US  Argentina               Albania  212000.00  26.50000  10/1/2015      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
28          28    E      US  Argentina               Albania  164459.08  20.70592  12/1/2015      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
29          29    E     AUC  Argentina               Albania  235810.00  49.22200   3/1/2015      Bovine      Beef      Frozen
querying cty_rpt AR
querying cty_rpt US
querying cty_rpt AUC
querying cty_rpt CN
querying cty_rpt KR
------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, flow, cty_rpt, origin, destination, value, qty1, date, animal_type, meat_type, temperature]
Index: []
------------------------------
    Unnamed: 0 flow cty_rpt     origin           destination    value    qty1       date animal_type meat_type temperature
3            3    E      US  Argentina  United Arab Emirates   1078.0   0.153  10/1/2014      Bovine      Beef     Chilled
13          13    E      US  Argentina                Angola  61430.0  10.850   4/1/2014      Bovine      Beef     Chilled
------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, flow, cty_rpt, origin, destination, value, qty1, date, animal_type, meat_type, temperature]
Index: []
------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, flow, cty_rpt, origin, destination, value, qty1, date, animal_type, meat_type, temperature]
Index: []
------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, flow, cty_rpt, origin, destination, value, qty1, date, animal_type, meat_type, temperature]
Index: []
```